# Azure Search filter on the whole field

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've been trying to create a filter matching the end of the whole field text.
For example, taking a text field with the text:  `the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`

I would like it to match with a query that searches for fields with values ending with *g*. Something like:

```
{
  "search":"*",
  "queryType":"full",
  "searchMode": "any",
  ...
  "filter":"search.ismatchscoring('/g$/','MyField')"
}
```

The result is only records where MyField contains values with words composed by a the single *g* character anywhere on the string.

Using the filter directly also produces no results:

```
{
  "search":"*",
  "queryType":"full",
  "searchMode": "any",
  ...
  "filter":"MyField eq '*g'"
}
```

As far as I can see, the tokenization will always be the base for the search and filter, which means that on the above query, *$* is completely ignored and matches will be by word, not by field.

Probably I could use the `keyword_v2` analyzer on this field but then I would lose the tokenizarion that I use when searching normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be defining a second field in your index, with the same value as ‘MyField’, but with a different analyzer (e.g. `keyword_v2`). That way you may still search over the original field while filtering over the other.

Regardless, you might have simplified the filter for the sake of the example, but otherwise it seems redundant to use `search.ismatchscoring()` when not combining with another filter clause via ‘or’ – one can use the `search` parameter directly. 
Moreover, regex might not be working because the default **queryType** for `search.ismatchscoring()` is **simple**, not **full**  - [please see docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-odata-full-text-search-functions)

Comment: You're right, we're using `search.ismatchscoring()` because we have other filtering criteria; I'm using the query type full.
I thought of using the `keyword_v2` analyzer but that will also impact the other normal searches when I what to search by word on the same field. Duplicating the field with a different analyzer is also not so intuitive for consumption; whoever is querying the index needs to know the subtility.

I understand how the tokenization works, I was just wondering if there was a way to bypass it and query directly the full source records with a regex.

Comment: I ended up going with this option as there's no other way at the moment. Thanks